# Android ListArrayAdapter constructor never gets called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have some logging statements in my ListArrayAdapter constructor but it looks like they never get executed. The list shows up and is populated with the individual rows. Also, all of my private variables are set, so it looks like the constructor is doing its job, but I just don't see the logs.

When is the constructor called? I have

```
adapter = new MyListArrayAdapter(this, labelList, pageName);
```

in my activity, and it is called, but I don't see the logs.

```
public MyListArrayAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<ListLabels> labels, String pagename)
    {
        super();
        Log.d("MyListArrayAdapter", "Constructing a new MyListArrayAdapter");
        this.labelList = labels;
        this.pagename = pagename;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Comment: Are you seeing  other logs from your app?

Comment: How are you constructing the object? What is the super class for "MyListArrayAdapter"?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing other logs from the app.

Comment: Where in your activity are you creating this adapter?

Comment: is your class extending ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I am extending BaseAdapter. I am calling the constructor in my PageListActivity which extends ListActivity

Comment: Have you ever called setAdapter in your code? You should paste your code where you do that. That's where you adapter bind to a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is called when you initialize the Adapter object.

```
 MyListArrayAdapter adapter = new MyListArrayAdapter(// arguments here);
```

or

```
 listView.setAdapter(new MyListArrayAdapter(// arguments here));
```

As of why your log is not displayed in logcat, you should `set a break point at log in your constructor and then debug the program to see its behavior`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be called when you first initialize your adapter.

```
MyListArrayAdapter mListArrayAdapter = new MyListArrayAdapter(act, labels, pagename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, crap!

I had the tag spelled wrong for the log statement.

Thanks for the help though :)